# What happens if all instances are removed from rotation of Azure load balancer?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, internal-load-balancer

I'm thinking of creating a custom load balancer probe based on CPU usage to improve utilization, however in an event where all my instances are working very hard, all may be at max cpu and still progressing happily. Would this mean that based on my probe there would be no available instances to perform work as all would have been removed from rotation?

Answer (score 0):

> Would this mean that based on my probe there would be no available
>   instances to perform work as all would have been removed from
>   rotation?

Yes, if you create a custom load balancer probe based on CPU usage,  then your instances are working very hard, all may be at max cpu, your instances will return a non-200 status, LB will not route network traffic to them, so you can't access your service.